# location.href could not load new location?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to redirect to new location when a button is clicked. I have used `location.href=newloactionname.aspx` but it doesn't move to new location. My code is:

```
function OpenUser(userID) {               
    location.href = 'UserRegistration.aspx?userID=' + userID;
    alert(location.href)//shows only previous location
}
```

Comment: It should work assuming that it is called in global context (i.e., `window`). If it is not, try calling `window.location.href = ...`.

Comment: What calls this code? Does the alert fire?

Comment: the alerted location will be the current page, because the current page hasn't changed yet

Comment: I have tried window.location.href , still no change. The alerted location is current page. I need to redirect to the specified location instead of staying in the current page.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
window.location = 'UserRegistration.aspx?userID=' + userID;
```

instead...

Comment: No Its not working. Is there any problem in including javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

See first if you have any javasript errors. Maybe your code does not calling OpenUser function.

Also try this:

//link click
window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

OR

// HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/");

I almost sure that you have an JS error somewhere. Press F12 on your browser.
Put an alert on the function. See if the alert appears.